# Pubilsh my wbsite

Tags: visual-studio, web, publish

I have created a  website using visual studio 2008. Now i want to run this website in my friend PC. His PC does not has Visual studio installed. How can i run that web site in his PC.
I have given my website folder him in PenDrive.

Comment: You need to install and use IIS on your friend's machine. Get IIS Express.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is very easy.
you should install IIS in your system. and make a virtual directory.
store your application intpub/www.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install IIS and ASP.NET on your friend's machine.

You can do this using the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), a free (and awesome) Microsoft tool that should give you everything you need including IIS, ASP.NET, .NET Framework and anything else you may require.

Comment: After Installing IIS and ASP.NET in my friend PC, In which place i should save my website and how can run my website. please write steps.

Comment: Usually it's C:/inetpub/wwwroot